# Pop-up message: assert failed

Tags: popup

What does a pop up that says assert failed mean?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Without a bit more context we're not going to be able to help much. Is this popup coming from a program you've *written* - in which case tell us more about it; or from a program you're merely *using* - in which case it generally indicates a bug and/or an unrecoverable error, but either way, questions about programs you're *using* should be asked at http://superuser.com rather than here.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't written the language you are using, but the popup tries to say that an assertion statement has failed. Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assertion_(computing)) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

It means that an internal assumption that the program was making turned out to be wrong.  This typically implies that the program is close to complete failure and should exit immediately..